How can I achieve a background like in flutter given this kind of image?
I have a figma design like this
Figma Design and confused how to achieve this.
So I've already try using custom painter & 9 patch using this library https://pub.dev/packages/ninepatch_image but not quite the result I want.
The result when I use CustomPainter look like this:

and 9 patch look like this:

...while this result is better than the CustomPainter but I need the yellow Container to be fill the parent container
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

check examples provided with roundPolygon

@pskink sure, will check it later
